# Finding base address of DLL in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, memory, dll

So I asked a similar question about 2 weeks back about how to find the base address of a application but now Im also wondering on how to find it for a DLL ? (not the dll of the application im building but of another application running on the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
    For Each _process As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If (CanAccessProcess(_process)) Then
            For Each _module As ProcessModule In _process.Modules
                Console.WriteLine(_module.BaseAddress)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Function CanAccessProcess(_process As Process)
    Try
        Dim temp As ProcessModule = _process.MainModule
        temp = Nothing
    Catch ex As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        ' Its probably a 64 bit process
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

This will simply show all BaseAddresses of all modules of all processes that we can access. It tries to access the process its main module first to see if the exception raises. If it raises we know we don't have access to the process.

Comment: This gives me the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Unable to enumerate the process modules.

Comment: The exact error is `Additional information: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.`. You can't access a 64 bit process from a 32 bit process. I'll update the code for it.

Comment: I cant seem to make any use of this... i need it to display the base address somewhere and im not sure how to get it from the Console.ReadLine() how would i do that ? say in a textbox or listbox ?

Comment: I used a console application, you don't need Console.WriteLine and ReadLine. If you want to display it in a ListBox for example you have to change the Console.WriteLine(..) part with `yourListBox.Items.Add(_module.BaseAddress)`

Comment: ok that works i was just being stupid >.> but is there any way to clarify the dll name or the process its in ?

Comment: So even if i list all processes It doesnt seem to find the dll I need :C

Comment: You have to build your application as 64 bit. I guess the process you are trying to acces is 64 bit.

Comment: ok I seem to have most everything working my only problem now is I'm left with 30+ values how would i go about only adding the base address of say "server.dll" to the listbox ?

Comment: Change `_module.BaseAddress` to `String.Format("Name: {0} BaseAddress: {1}", _module.ModuleName, _module.BaseAddress)`. This will generate a string that adds 'Name: System.dll BaseAddress: 100000000'.

Comment: how would i go about filtering out only that line ? say text box1.text = listbox1.items.server.dll (not exactly that but you get the point)

Comment: I'm sorry? I don't get what you mean. Besides, that seems like a whole other question to me, I think you should ask a new question for that (search Google/StackOverflow first ofcourse)..